# SSRS - Replacing a null value in an 'decimal' column with the 'string' message?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

I have the following table:

```
item_ID  |  item_Name  |  Amount
---------|-------------|-------
   12    |    apple    |  $1
   13    |    orange   | <null>
   14    |    grapes   |  $2.5
```

For the 'null' value for the 'orange' item, I'd like to replace it with the string 'N/A', even though the column the data comes from is an decimal.  Is it possible?

I tried putting in the expression for that column as follows:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value), Sum(Fields!Amount.Value), 'N/A')
```

But I got an error and the report failed.

Comment: No, this is not possible.  A decimal column cannot contain a string value.  You *could* convert all the values to strings, if you want to store strings as values for `cost`.

Comment: It is best to leave that column as a decimal until the presentation layer. that way for line item you can create an expression to display as whatever you want. And in summary your aggregates will still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you handle this at the report layer in SSRS you'll get a few advantages: exports of the data will export these as numbers still, for example.

Set the value of the textbox that you are using something similar to

```
=IIF( IsNothing(Fields!Cost.Value ), "N/A",Fields!Cost.Value)
```

Comment: I was waiting on you to post this approach as I rarely use `ssrs`.  +1, nice example.

Comment: I was in the process of writing this out based on my comment

Comment: Yep, this is the one that solved it for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `coalesce` with `cast`:

```
select item_ID, item_Name, coalesce(cast(cost as varchar(100)), 'N/A') as cost
from yourtable;
```

Comment: Since this is tagged with `Reporting-Services` it would probably be better to use the presentation layer for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ISNULL function

```
SELECT cost = ISNULL( TRY_CAST( cost as varchar(50), 'N/A' )
```

Comment: Great alternative and love that you're a new contributor.  Just realize you also need to use `cast` or `convert` with this option as well.

Comment: Ah good catch, I missed that it was coming from a decimal field. Answer updated to include the cast. Thanks!